# Compare all services on the local computer with referent list of allowed services stored in .html file - Powershell

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, scripting, windows-scripting

I need a script in **powershell** that will check the status of all services on the local computer and compare with the reference list of allowed services stored in the .html file I created earlier. After the comparison, the script will stop all services running on the computer that are not listed in the reference file.

Comment: HTML is not the best storage format for structured data. Why not use a simple list or a CSV file?

Comment: I agree with you, but I need a solution for already defined exercise.

Comment: Show us your HTML then.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I created HTML file with command Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | ConvertTo-Html -As LIST | Out-File services.htm 
I found this cmdlet on this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html?view=powershell-7.2#example-6--create-a-web-page-to-display-service-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i would like to say this code has no validation and will not work well with other html tables. And it is not optimized at all.

```
$ServicesFromHTML = (gc .\services.htm | where {$_ -match '^<tr><td>(Name:|Status:|<hr>)'}) -replace "</?t(r|d)>","" -join ";" -replace ";<hr>;","`r`n" -replace "(Name:|Status:)","" | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Header "Name","Status"
$RunningServices = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Select Name,Status
"Comparing services if they are currently running ("<=") or were running when exported ("=>")"
Compare-Object $RunningServices.Name $ServicesFromHTML.Name
$OnlyNowRunningServices = (Compare-Object $RunningServices.Name $ServicesFromHTML.Name | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="}).InputObject
$OnlyNowRunningServices | foreach {"Trying to stop Service $_";Stop-Service $_}
```

For the future use CSV/XML/JSON export as you can import them quite easy. If you need something human readable to read in browser, then create it additionaly.